# How to get Typeform response in node js app?

Tags: node.js, express, hapi.js, typeform

I am try to implement Typeform in nodejs app. To get typeform responses I need to call
[https://api.typeform.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={your_client_id}&redirect_uri=https://results-example.herokuapp.com/callback&scope={scope1}+{scope2}+{scope3}](https://api.typeform.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=%7Byour_client_id%7D&redirect_uri=https://results-example.herokuapp.com/callback&scope=%7Bscope1%7D+%7Bscope2%7D+%7Bscope3%7D) and it continues to a consent screen that lists the scope of access for my app and prompts them to grant or deny access to my app. After accepting the url changes to the redirect url and gives a code in url query.
but when I am calling this typeform api using Request module in my node app, it is not continuing to the consent screen.
So how can I bypass the consent screen in nodejs app or get the code I need?

Here is the code snippet

```js
app.get('/typeform', (req, res) => {
  request('https://admin.typeform.com/oauth/authorize?client_id="client_id"&redirect_uri="hosturl/typeform"&scope=responses:read+responses:write', function (error, response, body) {
if(!error){
    console.log(response, Body);
    }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are dealing with oAuth.

oAuth is useful if you need to access the typeform responses on the behalf of someone. Through oAuth they will grant you access to their account. Similar to all the "sign it with facebook/google" button you see everywhere on the internet.

If you need to access the responses of your own Typeform account, you might not need to go through this hassle, you can just create a personal token in your account settings and call directly the [Responses API](https://developer.typeform.com/responses/reference/retrieve-responses/).

If you want to continue the oauth route, it's a two steps process as explained on [Typeform Documentation](https://developer.typeform.com/get-started/applications/).

1. First, you redirect the user to `https://api.typeform.com/oauth/authorize...`
2. The user sees the screen you described and authorize your application to access their account.
3. Then they are redirected to the url you have defined as `redirect_uri`. There you need to extract the `code` query parameter passed from the request.
4. You exchange this code, for an `access_token`, which will help you make calls to the Typeform API on behalf of the user. To do so you make an API call to `https://api.typeform.com/oauth/token` with all the parameters.
5. If everything went well you should get back a JSON with `access_token`, you can now use it to make a call to the Responses API.

Does it make sense?

If you are using Node.js, you can use a library called Passport, that handles most of this dance for you. [Here](https://glitch.com/%7Etf-oauth-boilerplate) is an example on how to use it with Typeform.
And [here](https://glitch.com/%7Etf-oauth-no-passport) is an example without using it, making the calls directly.

Finally, if you are not familiar with oAuth, I would recommend you to read articles like [this one](https://dev.to/anabella/dancing-with-oauth-emp) from Anabella Spinelli, that breaks down the concepts.

Comment: The key error in OP's formulation is performing a `request` to the authorization URL instead of redirecting the user to the authorization URL (`res.redirect()` in Express). In addition to open source libraries like Passport.js, there are managed OAuth services that work with Typeform, like [Xkit's Typeform connector](https://app.xkit.co/connectors/new/typeform) which is my day job.

Comment: On point 4, you need to make an HTTP call to `https://api.typeform.com/oauth/token` as described here: https://developer.typeform.com/get-started/applications/#3-write-your-application

Once you have exchanged this code for an `access_token` you can make authenticated calls to Typeform API.

Comment: I have got the code.
Now I am calling the https://api.typeform.com/oauth/token to get access_token using post call with a request body containing grant-type, code, client_id, client_secret and redirect_uri exactly same as mentiontioned in documentation https://developer.typeform.com/get-started/applications/.
But I am getting this error
{
code: 'bad_request',
description: 'Bad request',
help: 'http://developers.typeform.com/get-started/authentication/'
}

Comment: probably worth contacting typeform support directly at this point so they can help you out better.